# How to import a library into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The Oboe library is an Android library that contains lots of examples that are also useful for using in my apps. It's structured in a weird way: https://github.com/google/oboe

On the past I copied this structure into my app structure. That is, I placed the root CMakeLists.txt file into my project's root, the root folders on my project's root, etc. This ended up in a mess because I couldn't update oboe to a new version without having to carefully updating each folder by hand.

How can I import oboe into my project as a separate folder and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.oboe:oboe:1.4.3'
}
```

Also enable prefab by adding:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        prefab true
    }
}
```

**Include and link to oboe by updating your CMakeLists.txt:**

```
android { 
    defaultConfig { 
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add their latest version dependency into your gradle file, you shouldn't copy and paste their files/code directly to your project

here's the dependency line

```
implementation 'com.google.oboe:oboe:1.5.0'
```

found in this link:
https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md

they should probably move that part and add it into the Readme file in their github page, since that's the normal